# How to create a close, maximize and minimize buttons without remote?

Tags: electron

Creating a frameless window, I need the 3 action buttons to "close", "minimize" and "maximize".

I used to create them just like this:

Inside my main.js:

```
function createWindow () {
  const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    (...)
    frame:false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      (...)
    }
  })
```

And Inside my page JS file, I just used to write:

```
const {remote} = require('electron');

function close() {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.close();
  }

function minimize() {
    var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
    window.minimize();
  }
```

It still works.. But I get this warning:

**"Electron Deprecation Warning The 'remote' module is deprecated and will be disabled by default in a future version of Electron. To ensure a smooth upgrade and silence this warning, specify {enableRemoteModule: true} in the WebPreferences for this window."**

And I really can't find a way to do this actions without using remote.
I appreciate any help!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should send a message from your renderer process to the main process.

so in your renderer process add a event to your maximize button and send a message with:

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
ipc.send('max');
```

in your main process receive this message with:

```
ipcMain.on('max', () => {
    //mainWindow is the reference to your window
    mainWindow.maximize()
})
```

to enable ipcMain in your main process add ipcMain like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron');
```

here an example to visualise the main process:
[image: receive message from ipc in electron main process]

[Here is the breaking changes note from electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#default-changed-enableremotemodule-defaults-to-false)
[Here is a good article about it](https://medium.com/@nornagon/electrons-remote-module-considered-harmful-70d69500f31)

Comment: Works great. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding an ipc listener inside of the createWindow method (which may lead to some issues especially when dealing with multiple windows), u can use BrowserWindow static methods.
for example, I had a reloading button in my menus and I could achieve what I wanted by this (on main process, u can use a ipcRenderer to call it from renderer process):

```
menuTemplate.push({
                label: app.getName(),
                submenu: [
                    {role: 'about'},
                    {type: 'separator'},
                    {
                        label: 'return to previous page',
                        click: () => BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.goBack(),
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'refresh',
                        click: () => BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().webContents.reloadIgnoringCache(),
                    }
                ]
});
```

the **BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow()** did the trick for me